# using R to plot the mean line of multiple lines

Tags: r, plot

I would like to know how to use R to plot the mean line from several individual lines as shown in this figure and obtain the value of both ends from each local segment of the mean line.

[image]
In the sub-figure on chr 1, 
solid gray lines: each recombination rate 
Solid red line: Mean local recombination rate

For instance, how could I plot the mean line for these two files 
( 1th column as x axis: position; 2nd column as y axis)

individual 1:

```
27343,0.014909
271377,0.044878
1166716,0.005004
1384732,0.018162
1917139,0.006432
2229415,0.011650
2736279,0.008127
3162852,0.019351
3619476,0.014546
4233682,0.005321
```

individual 2:

```
27343,0.045651
778236,0.032515
1166716,0.012292
1603469,0.026068
2287470,0.011058
2904105,0.019674
3619476,0.012513
4448082,0.012442
5010563,0.009084
5535964,0.008281
```

Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Try ggplot2 -- see http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_smooth.html for example.

Comment: Thank you. But, it's not what I want. I would like to plot the similar mean polygonal line shown in the figure for multiple polygonal lines.

Comment: Do you have a definition of "mean line". Do you not want to do some type of smoothing? Clearly you cannot do linear regression in the case of recombination rate. Do you really just want to calculate the mean of y observations at each x and plot that?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am not against smoothing and also want to acquire the fitted value of both ends of each segment.

Comment: @wedi10 `geom_smooth` will do that.